# CardView - refresh images on visible items only

Tags: java, android, image, list, refresh

I have cardview list with each item containing image view and text. Each image for each item is provided as url with image to download.

Now, instead of converting each image to bitmap and putting it into my adapter I want to get functionality similar to Google Play search results, where images are refreshing after list is shown.

My idea is to use Universal Image Loader: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader so my images will be loaded in background.

However, I have no idea how to force refreshing only visible items. The rest should be refreshed on scroll, just after they appear when list is scrolled down. So basically, the same as it works in Google Playstore app.

Any tips?

Comment: Why do you want to force refreshing only visible items? Visible items are updated when they are visible. I do not understand your problem? Indeed, Universal Image Loader is a good solution to loaded image in background but Ithink Picasso library is better :).

Comment: If you are using an adapter view like `ListView` or `RecyclerView` to hold your `CardView`s, you should get visible items refreshed just by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  In your `getView()`, you set up your `ImageView` with UIL and it should take care of the rest, including canceling the download when the image is recycled.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, there is nothing special to do to get functionality I want, it's enough to use universal image loader? All I need is to get item image refreshed in background just aftet item become visible after list scroll